# Runnable code is looping its actions

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

I didn't understand the code snippets below. This is the code snippets I took from **AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl** class of android. These below things I didn't understand.

1) var1 is assigned as final, but we are changing it in the body of execute.

2) var1 points the memory address of Runnable object that is created from "new Runnable() {....}". Inside that Runnable object's heap memory, there is run() method.  This run() method uses AccessController class variable to reach up to doPrivileged() method of AccessControler, which contains memory address of newly created PrivilegedAction object and var3 as its parameters. But This newly created PrivilegedAction object again calls its run() method to call var1's run() method. It's kind of looping the actions.

3)So var1 points to fixed position always because its final. It can call its run method because run() method is inside it's memory address. But, new PrivilegedAction object, you create each time, is not defined and consistent. We can't say this object contains this much heap memory space because insider there, it is asking var1 again to run its run() method as var1.run()

I wanna know how this snippet is changing the memory structure inside system? I want to know in terms of Computer Architecture perspective.

```
public final void execute(final Runnable var1) {
        SecurityManager var2 = System.getSecurityManager();
        if(var2 != null) {
            final AccessControlContext var3 = AccessController.getContext();
            var1 = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
                        public Void run() {
                            var1.run();
                            return null;
                        }
                    }, var3);
                }
            };
        }

        this.executeOnPooledThread(var1);
    }
```

Comment: This would not even compile... You cannot asign to final variable..

Comment: @Selvin, I didn't ask you to compile, I asked to understand this code. Why do you want to compile this? I explained everything above. And can I know, why did you downgrade my question?

Comment: **It is not valid java code...** What do you not understand?

Comment: And, I said, this snippet is from the Android class AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl decompiled class. This class is part of the Android library and is 100% valid.

Comment: No, it is not... I had even find this class code and it is different. In both android and openjdk. Again the code that you had provided **is not a valid java code**

Comment: [Link](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java). In above link, there is no code snippet, which I posted. But in my Android Studio, there is the exact same code, which I posted. I don't know how Android studio is creating java byte code?

Comment: You can provide me the logic of code snippet between lines 315 to 337 of this file. Here is the link.   [Link] (https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java)

Comment: final Runnable delegate = task; //from this line, I know delegate Runnable is final, so it can't be changed. But delegate is function of task. Here task is dependent variable, delegate depends on task. To be delegate remained unchanged, task also should be unchanged. task hold the address of new Runnable object. It means, now delegate also holds the address of the same object. At first run() method calls  AccessController's static method doPrivileged, which further uses the same final delegate to run the run() method. So, the process is not reaching up to "return null" line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java decompiled byte code is not for the programmer. Dont put your logic there.